# Python - application to search excel database column - Using tkinter Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

The application should search one of the column in an excel and and display corresponding column as  a result but i am not able to get the values. I think i am not able to map the dictionary to the display tab using tkinter. Please help.

Below file is in outlook
Search (Input)    Result (Output)
1                  a
2                  b
3                  c
4                  d

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import pandas as pd
root=Tk()
root.geometry('450x550')
root.title("Welcome")
root.configure(background="silver")

#Entry widget object

textin=StringVar()    
**exlist = pd.read_excel('foo6.xls', index_col=0).to_dict('index')**

def clk():
     entered = ent.get()
     output.delete(0.0,END)
     try:
          textin = exlist[entered]
     except:
          textin = 'SORRY NO INFO \n AVAILABLE!!!!!!!!\n'
     output.insert(0.0,textin)

def ex():
   tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Program",'Exit')
   exit()

def exitt():
     tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Program",'Exit')
     exit()   

def me():
     text='\n XYZ \n Piyushrkc \n Nice'
     saveFile=open('text.txt','w')
     saveFile.write(text)
     print('This are the entries::',text)


def hel():
   help(tkinter)

def cont():
     tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("S/W Contributors",'\n Piyush ___Version 1.0___')

def clr():
     textin.set(" ")


menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subm = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subm)
subm.add_command(label="Memo",command=me)
subm.add_command(label="Save")
subm.add_command(label="Save As")
subm.add_command(label="Print")
subm.add_command(label="Exit",command=ex)

subm1 = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Tools",menu=subm1)
subm1.add_command(label="Tkinter Help",command=hel)

subm2 = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="About",menu=subm2)
subm2.add_command(label="Contributors",command=cont)


lab=Label(root,text='Name :',font=('none 20 bold'))
lab.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

ent=Entry(root,width=20,font=('none 18 bold'),textvar=textin,bg='white')
ent.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W)


but=Button(root,padx=2,pady=2,text='Submit',command=clk,bg='powder blue',font=('none 18 bold'))
but.place(x=100,y=90)


but4=Button(root,padx=2,pady=2,text='Clear',font=('none 18 bold'),bg='powder blue',command=clr)
but4.place(x=220,y=90)



output=Text(root,width=20,height=8,font=('Time 20 bold'),fg="black")
output.place(x=100,y=200)


labb=Label(root,text='Results',font=('non 18 bold'))
labb.place(x=0,y=180)


but1=Button(root,padx=2,pady=2,text='Exit',command=exitt,bg='powder blue',font=('none 18 bold'))
but1.place(x=200,y=470)


root.mainloop()
```